# How check the uniqueness of elements in TreeSet when read from XML with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want an exception to be thrown when trying to add a duplicate

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage>
    <route>
        <id>1</id>
    </route>
    <route>
        <id>1</id>    <--
    </route>
</storage>
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "storage")
public class RouteStorage {
    @XmlElement(name = "route")
    private TreeSet<Route> storage = new TreeSet<Route>();
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "route")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Route implements Comparable<Route> {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Route o) {
        return Comparator.comparing(Route::getId)
                .compare(this, o);
    }
}
```

There will now only be one `Route` in `storage`. Is it possible to get an exception?

Comment: TreeSet itself wouldn't throw an exception but you could try to pass a comparator that throws an exception if any 2 routes are equal (or throw it in `Route.compareTo()` but I'd rather put that "property" into the TreeSet).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own subclass of `TreeSet` which throws
an exception whenever someone tries to add a duplicate element.
And then you use this set in your `RouteStorage` class:

```
/**
 * WARNING: This implementation violates the specification of <code>Set</code>.
 */
private static class MyTreeSet<E> extends TreeSet<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (contains(e))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate element " + e);
        return super.add(e);
    }
}

@XmlElement(name = "route")
private TreeSet<Route> storage = new MyTreeSet<Route>();
```

Comment: Yes this will work, though there are theoretical objections: your subclass doesn't satisfy the contract for a java Set. Also, I think it should preferably be an IllegalStateException, not an IllegalArgumentException. Also, for efficiency, you can do the add() and test the result, rather than doing a separate contains() call.

Comment: @MichaelKay Agreed, you make a valid objection. The subclass violates the specification of `Set`. I recommend at least some bold-faced javadoc warning about this, and may be making it a private inner class to prevent accidental use elsewhere.